# How to return a JsonModel error from a dispatch event in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO**

I have a PHP application using the Zend Framework 2 and it has a "visual" side (where it returns nice HTML web pages) and an API side (where it simply returns JSON). When a request is sent to our server it's routed through the `onBootstrap( \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent )` function in `Module.php`. The bootstrap function does some general setup and checks (is the user signed in...etc.) and then attaches a dispatch function for `\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController`'s (our API controllers) and another dispatch function for `\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController`(our "Visual" controllers).

In the dispatch functions more session specific stuff is checked and setup and occasionally an error can occur. If an error occurs in the `\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController`'s dispatch function then it simply returns the error message to the view and the view displays it to the user. If an error occurs in the `\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController`'s dispatch function I want it to return a JsonModel with the error information and an appropriate response header (400,404...etc).

**WHAT'S HAPPENING**

When an error occurs in the `\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController`'s dispatch function the response header is set but the body isn't. On top of that the action is still routed to the controller so if the controller specifies a new response header then that overrides the previous one.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
public function onBootstrap( \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $event ) {

    ...

    $event_manager          = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $shared_manager         = $event_manager->getSharedManager();

    ...

    // Dispatch event for AbstractRestfulController calls
    $shared_manager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController', 'dispatch', function($event) {

        ...

        try {
            $organization = $organization_interface->get($id);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $event->getResponse()->setStatusCode($e->getCode());
            return new JsonModel(array(
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            ));
        }

        ...

    }, 100);

    ...

}
```

So I know that the returned JsonModel won't work because it's being returned from the dispatch function and not the controller. What I want to know is an "easy" way to send my JsonModel as the response AND stop the framework from running the routed action in the controller.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the string to be returned from that JSON Model then this should be enough -

It is obvious to get the action getting dispatch and not the JSON Model, so try this -

instead of -

```
return new JsonModel(array(
    'error' => $e->getMessage(),
));
```

write

```
$view = new JsonModel(array(
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
        ));

echo $view->serialize();
http_response_code($e->getCode());    //Added the line of code as per suggested in the comment by B1NARY
exit();
```

This will return the JSON string.

Let us know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Did you mean "$view = new JsonModel(array(
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
        ));"? It returns the body correctly (yay!) but the header has the value 200 instead of the value I specify.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the line of code. Will look into the header issue.

Comment: Your answer is correct, you just needed to add `http_response_code($e->getCode());` before `exit;`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is, for me, a better zf2ish solution :

```
$this->response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_401);
$viewModel = new JsonModel(['error' => 'Unauthorized', 'error_description' => $exception->getMessage()]);
$event->setViewModel($viewModel);
$event->stopPropagation(true);
return $viewModel;
```